# Backup plan to Heroku

Tags: backup, heroku

We host our application on Heroku. I'm wondering what can I do as a backup plan when Heroku doesn't work.

If I keep a backup of everything on Rackspace, when Heroku goes down, can I change to Rackspace in the moment? Any idea how that's done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, if everything works and is synced from Heroku to Rackspace (database and files) then you can just switch over.

Most fail-overs like this are done by changing the DNS record from your Heroku IP to your rackspace IP.

Comment: is there any place where I Can read more about how to do this? thanks

Comment: you just setup an environment that works with your application, and sync the databases. Changing your DNS records should be quite straight forward I think. There is no definite guide on this, you will need to check the tools you have on your platforms (rsync on linux for example to sync files). And replicating the database is entirely dependent on your database software.